# Export Layout as PDF in QGIS3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

I am trying to export a specific `layout` with `python` in `QGIS3`. But I am struggling with the `QgsLayoutExport` class. How do you use it? How can specify which `layout` should be exported? This is the code I tried but it's not working. The `layout` in the brackets is the `layout` I want to export.

```
QgsLayoutExporter(layout).exportToPdf(filepath)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This a basic example how export to pdf where you can espify the layout.

```
projectInstance = QgsProject.instance()
layoutmanager = projectInstance.layoutManager()
layout = layoutmanager.layoutByName("test") #Layout name
exporter = QgsLayoutExporter(layout)
exporter.exportToPdf("C://test.pdf", QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings() )
```

Answer (score 4):

You will also need to include [PdfExportSettings()](https://qgis.org/api/structQgsLayoutExporter_1_1PdfExportSettings.html) when using the [exportToPdf()](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutExporter.html#a0d5bdecfc7e15618c1d52b3184b53215) method. You can call the default values using `QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings()`.

---

So your code could look like:

```
QgsLayoutExporter(layout).exportToPdf( filepath, QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings() )
```