# QGIS 3 export report in Python

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, qgis-print-layouts

In QGIS we have new layout type: Report. I didn't find tutoral to export this in PDF in Python.
Where can I find Python code examples?

Comment: possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/269058/49538

Comment: QgsLayoutExporter not work with qgsreport. This is my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QgsLayoutExporter` if work with `QgsReport`, but the way you export it changes a bit.

Here is a basic example of how to export report to PDF

```
projectInstance = QgsProject.instance()
layoutmanager = projectInstance.layoutManager()
r = layoutmanager.layoutByName("test") #report name
settings = QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings() # default settings
result, error = QgsLayoutExporter.exportToPdf(r, "D://test.pdf", settings)
```

[exportToPdf](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsLayoutExporter.html#a0d5bdecfc7e15618c1d52b3184b53215)